# To show custom message in Symfony forms?

Tags: php, symfony1

Want to show a custom message in form's error list, if the two fields did not match.
the from is as follows,
 'old_password'            =>'Old Password*',
 'new_password'            =>'New Password*',
 'confirm_password'        =>'Confirm Password*',
I want that the old password should match the value from the database, the value in new password and confirm password should also match.
please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony 1.1 and later, to compare if the two form fields match you need to set up a post validator, like:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
  new sfValidatorSchemaCompare(
    'new_password', 
    sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 
    'confirm_password',
    array(),
    array('invalid' => 'Your custom error message here!!')
  )
);
```

Try reading [Symfony forms in Action](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/), it should solve most of your problems about form creation and validation within the Symfony framework